# c# pass a list as parameter function

Tags: c#, parameters

"Hey, use a list of parameters or use param", but the problem doesn't come from there.
I have functions which take no parameter, one or many integers, ... the user enter the name of a function and a list of parameters and i want to call the function and give the list to it.
For exemple :

```
//void AddUser(int32 age, String name)
List<dynamic> UserList = new List<dynamic>();
UserList.Add(42); UserList.Add("toto");
String FunctionEntered = "AddPerson";

MyFramwork.Call(FunctionEntered, UserList);
//gives UserList(List)
```

And i can't modify the function entered to allow it to take a List of dynamic values as parameters. So i need a solution to call a function (i don't know the number of parameters) and use the index 1,2,... of a list as the first, second, ... parameter.

Thanks.

PS : don't worry, my framework allows me to call an unknown function just using it's name.

Edit : I'll try to clarify, I have a List and i want to call a function with this list as parameter but the function that i want to call don't take Lists as parameter (and i can't modify the function).
For exemple I want to use List{a, b} as parameter of Sum(int a, int b) but I can't modify the function so i can't remplace the function by Sum(int[] ab) or Sum(List ab) and the number of arguments are variable so I can't call : Sum(myList[0], myList[1]).

Comment: Use reflection, find appropriate method by it's name ("AddPerson"), and then invoke this method passing list and other possible parameters as arguments.

Comment: I honestly dont understand what is your problem and what you want to achieve. Can you clarify a bit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
        public void CallMethod(List<dynamic> @params , string methodName , Type t){
        var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(methodName);
        List<object> convertedParams = new List<object>();
        var methodParameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

        for(int i=0;i<methodParameters.Length;i++)
        {
            convertedParams.Add(Convert.ChangeType(@params[i] , methodParameters[i].ParameterType));
        }

        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        methodInfo.Invoke(obj , convertedParams.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/params

See above and below........SumParameters can take in any number of int parameters. So I guess you can adjust for your needs.

```
static int SumParameters(params int[] values)
{
// Loop through and sum the integers in the array.
int total = 0;
foreach (int value in values)
{
    total += value;
}
return total;
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the original function, it takes only one int and one String as parameters (i can't modify it to take a list of dynamics as parameter). 
But i have a List<dynamic> to the function, and i can't give it.

Comment: If you can't modify the function to accept a parameter list, you'll have to create a wrapper function to repeatedly call it for each item in the list.

Comment: Can u give me an exemple of wrapper ? i'm struggeling with this : 
void titi(params object[] args)
        {
            toto((args);
        }
        void toto(int a, int b=0)
        {
            PackageHost.WriteDebug($"{a + b}");
        }
titi(new dynamic[2] {1,1})

Comment: @psyked you just need to find a method accepting a list and then loop around the values in the list calling your other method only accepting one item.

Comment: my function doesn't accept only one item, it has as much parameters as the list has indexs (list.length = X, number of parameters  = X) and i must call the function only one time